# I am getting error when trying to install sfpowerkit in my mac machine

Tags: sfdx

Ran the command sfdx plugins:install sfpowerkit, I see sfpowerkit installation is failed with errors as ›   Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir.

I have tried using sudo command as well sudo sfdx plugins:install sfpowerkit but seeing error as
Error: /usr/local/lib/sf/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js add
sfpowerkit@latest --non-interactive